# React Native + Icons: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key tintColor supplied to ForwardRef(Text)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ui-kitten

In a basic react-native app with bottom navigation tabs,

```
<BottomNavigationTab title='Baz' icon={() => <Icon name='line-chart' size={20} color='#000' />} />
```

shows the error message

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `tintColor` supplied to `ForwardRef(Text)`.

However if we were to remove `Icon` element, then

```
<BottomNavigationTab title='Baz />
```

works fine.

**Question:** What is causing this and how can we fix it?

Using

- `react-native-vector-icons` v6.0.0
- `react-navigation` v3.11.0
- `react-native` https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"
- `react-native-ui-kitten` v4.1.0

**Full Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { BottomNavigation, BottomNavigationTab, BottomNavigationProps, Avatar } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import ProfitScreen from '../screens/Profit';

class BottomNavigationShowcase extends React.Component {
    state = {
        selectedIndex: 0,
    };

    onTabSelect = (selectedIndex) => {
        this.setState({ selectedIndex });
    };

    render () {
        return (
            <BottomNavigation
                selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
                onSelect={this.onTabSelect}
            >
                <BottomNavigationTab title='Baz' icon={() => <Icon name='line-chart' size={20} color='#000' />} />
            </BottomNavigation>
        );
    }
}

const FooStack = createStackNavigator({
    Bar: BarScreen
})

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Foo: FooStack,
    }, {
        initialRouteName: 'Foo',
        tabBarComponent: BottomNavigationShowcase
    }
)

const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: TabNavigator,
}, {
    initialRoute: "Main"
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootNavigator);

export default AppContainer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody faced this issue - [here is an answer on Github](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/548#issuecomment-515673924)